# problema con regex preg_match php

Tags: array, regex

Buen dia a todos, yo tengo todo el dia tratando de resolver como hago para encontrar una coincidencia, por ejemplo, tengo esta cadena

```
$txt='1a.10.2a.210.22ac.23acd.24acd'
```

Yo debo validar que se encuentre el valor 23, junto a la letra C por ejemplo, pero TODO entre los "." el problema es que trato con lo siguiente

```
preg_match('/(23).*?(c)/', $txt, $output_array);
```

no funciona, porque aunque borre la letra C quedando de esta forma

```
$txt='1a.10.2a.210.22ac.23ad.24acd'
```

como la letra C, se encuentra en **24acd**, sigue encontrando coincidencia. En resumen necesitaria que solo se evalue entre los puntos(.), si el numero que le ingrese a buscar no se encuentra junto a la letra o por lo menos entre los puntos(.), significa que no encontro nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente: `23[^.]*c`

Así, en lugar de utilizar `.`, que permitiría cualquier caracter, utilizas `[^.]` que significa "cualquier caracter excepto el punto". De esta manera evitas "saltar" al siguiente grupo.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2QM6Uz/1/)**

Comment: Funciono, gracias de verdad amigo! En verdad me sorprende algo tan simple, por mas que trato de entenderlo, las guías en internet están en ingles y son muy pocas

Comment: @SeguisRafael Me alegra que te funcionara, en tal caso puedes marcar la respuesta como "aceptada". Es cierto que las mejores guías suelen estar en inglés.

Comment: amigo disculpa la molestia, pero ahora tengo el problema siguiente, si coloco **1a**.10.2a.210.2**1a**c.23adc.24acd, y coloco a buscar con el patron **1[^.]*a** aunque yo cambie el primer **1a** por **1b**, el patron encontrara 2**1a**c, entre los 2 puntos solo debe estar el numero exacto, no se si me entiendas

Comment: Listo amigo, ya lo solucione, con el siguiente patron, luego de publicar hace un momento una respuesta que no me funcionaba, pasar horas intentando, creo que por fin lo logre con el siguiente patron **\.?[^0-9]1[^0-9]*a\.?** y la cadena ahora quedaria asi -> **.1a.2a.21b.22acd.23acd.3a.31abcd.** Ocurre que estoy haciendo un array para los privilegios de un Usuario en PHP, 1,2,3 significa primer nivel, 21,22,23 significa los hijos del nivel 2, 31,32,33 significa los hijos del nivel 3 y asi, las letras a(buscar/ver), b(agregar), c(modificar), d(eliminar), son los privilegios de cada usuario

Comment: Lo hago asi, porque veo proyectos donde crean una tabla privilegios, entonces como estoy desarrollando una pagina donde hay muchos menus, cada usuario tiene acceso a distintas partes y yo decidi crear una columna para todo, en cambio una columna para cada privilegio luego resulta tediosa editar luego

Comment: Entonces quizás sería utilizar lo siguiente: `\b23[a-z]*c`  https://regex101.com/r/SYUET2/2/

Comment: Excelente funciona, que significa **\b** ?

Comment: Es límite de palabra. Sirve precisamente para buscar `1` pero no `11`. Significa que donde se encuentre `\b` la palabra no podría ser "ampliada". Ver: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#WordBoundary